# Matlab: How to restict access to sub-class of abstract class method

Tags: matlab, oop, subclass

Lets have a following three classes:

```
% Main class
classdef MjrClass < handle

   properties (SetAccess = immutable, GetAccess = public)
      cls;
   end

   methods (Access = public)
      function self = MjrClass()
         self.cls = SubClass(2);
      end
   end

end
```

```
% Abstract class
classdef (Abstract) AbsClass < handle

   properties (SetAccess = immutable, GetAccess = protected)
      p;
   end

   methods (Access = {?MjrClass})
      function self = AbsClass(parent)
         self.p = parent;
         self.do();
      end
   end

   methods (Access = public)
      function show(self)
         fprintf('self.p: %d\nself.c: %d\n', self.p, self.c)
      end
   end

end
```

```
% Sub-Class
classdef SubClass < AbsClass

   properties (SetAccess = private, GetAccess = public)
      c;
   end

   methods (Access = private)
      function do(self)
         self.c = self.p*2;
      end
   end

end
```

The logic is following. Main class `MjrClass` defines interface for end user. Inside, it creates (in general) several instances of `SubClass` class. Since those share some properties and methods they all inherit from `AbsClass` class. And because the `AbsClass` class alone has no purpose, it is defined as abstract class.

However as it is, Matlab complains it "Cannot access method 'AbsClass' in class 'AbsClass'". The problem is obviously the `Access` property of constructor method. But if I leave it public it does not reflect the fact that it shoould be instantiated only within `MjrClass` class.

The same problem applies to `do()` method of `SubClass` class, where `Access = private` should restrict the method to be called only once within the `AbsClass` constructor, not allowing user to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access specifier for the `AbsClass` constructor doesn't actually allow `AbsClass` to call that method. So, the fix is simple, allow `AbsClass` (and its subclasses) to call its own constructor, like this:

```
methods (Access = {?MjrClass, ?AbsClass})
    function obj = AbsClass(...)
     ....
```

Comment: That is actually sort of logical. Thank you. However Matlab says: *Access list — A list of one or more classes. Only the **defining class** and the classes in the list have access to the class members to which the attribute applies. If you specify a list of classes, MATLAB® does not allow access by any other class (that is, **access is private, except for the listed classes**).* So I thought that class can always access its own members.

Comment: Nevertheless, the class constructor still can not access the `do()` method.

Comment: Well no, `do` is `private` to the subclass. You could either make it `protected`, or give explicit access.

Comment: A little more on why the subclass cannot reach the constructor - in your case, attempting to construct an instance of `SubClass` _effectively_ uses the implicitly-defined `SubClass` constructor method. That method attempts to call the superclass constructor method, but is denied access. Once that problem is fixed, `AbsClass.AbsClass` attempts to call `SubClass.do`, but is denied because it is private. (And anyway, since `do` is not `abstract` in `AbsClass`, how can `AbsClass` be sure that `do` will even exist?)

Comment: I sort of understand everything. Just one note: If I make `do` method protected, it does not work either, that is the first thing i tried. The access must be specifically set to `AbsClass`. I guess it is because `protected` allows access from subclesses, but I need to access it from superclass.

Comment: It should work to _declare_ `do` to be `protected` and `Abstract` in `AbsClass`, and then define it in `SubClass`.

Comment: OK, now I get it. The reson for declaring abstract methods is so you cen set their properties in the superclass. Thank you one more time.